# best way to pass parameter to call back function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, jquery-callback

What is the best way to pass parameter to call back function in nodejs? I am replying on anonymous function but it been told that anonymous fuction reduce the performance.

I have a function which calls another function (getFiles) to get list of files and then I read files within a folder and compares whether the files in folder matches files returned by getFiles function.

```
function deleteMedia(req) {
    var files = getFiles();
    (function (parms) { //used to pass files
        fs.readdir(folderPath, function (err, fls) {
            console.log(parms);
        })
    })(files);
}
```

---

```
function getFiles(){
  var arr =[];
  arr.push('12.gif');
  arr.push('13.gif');
  arr.push('14.gif');
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: how are you calling this?

Comment: In this particular case, you can directly use `files` in the callback function

Comment: @thefourtheye: Can you please tell me how I can directly use `files` in the callback function?

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous functions only affect the performance if they are constantly being recreated and garbage collected. In that case storing a function permanently in the memory will make things faster.

If you are not calling deleteMedia a thousand times per second, you might not notice a decrease in your performance at all.

However in your case you can just skip the whole IIFE:

```
function deleteMedia(req) {
    var files = getFiles();
    fs.readdir(folderPath, function (err, fls) {
        console.log(files);
    });
}
```

Comment: for some reason when i say `console.log(files);  files` is coming as undefined for me. I am not sure if I have missed anything.

Comment: Are you using a different getFiles() method than the one you have posted in your question?

Comment: Nope. If i debug, I do see values in files array but when i go inside `readdir() files`  comes as undefined.

Comment: you are correct Sebastian . I am not sure what mistake I made earlier but now I am able to access `files` inside `readdir`. I was really confused as `closure` concept was not working.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't need to execute the block in parenthesis, it's not the asynchronous part. The readdir is asynchronous though, so that has your call back.

```
function deleteMedia(req) {
    var files = getFiles();
    for (var i in files){
        fs.readdir(files[i], function (err, fls) {
            // do something with output asynchronously
            console.log(fls);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use `files[]i` on`fs.readdir(files[i], function (err, fls) {`, instead i need to pass path of the folder which I want to read.